# PyTorch 2.0 in Raspberry Pi 4 has error: Illegal instruction

Tags: pytorch, raspberry-pi4

PyTorch 2.0 in Raspberry Pi 4 has error:  
Illegal instruction when I follow the https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ link for installation

1. Try to understand your RASPI OS ersion-> uname -a , it should be aarch64
2. Try to install previous version of pytorch like:
   `pip install torch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1 torchaudio==0.13.1`
3. Test with very basic code

```py
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

RESULT: problem has solved